# Change the cart item name for product variations in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I Would like to change the product variation text that appears in the cart once the product is added to cart. I suspect I'm suppose to use the `woocommerce_get_item_data` filter.

But I'm unsure how the code inside the function is suppose to be.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Gosh, I think I pasted a wrong link... of course it has nothing to do with it. I am sorry OP...

Comment: **To the communinty:** This question is not unclear and should be reopened (It's just short and doesn't provide any code)… The users that have voted this as unclear are not really skilled in WooCommerce/wordpress tagged questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_variation_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_item_name( $item_name,  $cart_item,  $cart_item_key ){
    // Change item name only if is a product variation
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type('variation') ){
        // HERE customize item name
        $item_name = __('my custom item name');

        // For cart page we add back the product link
        if(is_cart())
            $item_name = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $cart_item['data']->get_permalink() ), $item_name );
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and working